# How do i return a nonblank line list from another list with white space removed?

Tags: python

```
def get_poem_lines(poem):
    r""" (str) -> list of str

    Return the non-blank, non-empty lines of poem, with whitespace removed 
    from the beginning and end of each line.

    >>> get_poem_lines('The first line leads off,\n\n\n'
    ... + 'With a gap before the next.\nThen the poem ends.\n')
    ['The first line leads off,', 'With a gap before the next.', 'Then the poem ends.']
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your function?

Answer (score 1):

```
result = [line.strip() for line in string.split('\n') if line]
```